# PHP preg_match_all - how to get a content from HTML?

Tags: php, html, regex

$Content contains HTML document

```
   $contents = curl_exec ($ch)
```

I need to get a content from:

```
 <span class="Menu1">Artur €2000</span>
```

It's repeated several times so I want to save it into Array

I try to do that this way:

```
 preg_match_all('<span class=\"Menu1\">(.*?)</span>@si',$contents,$wynik2);
```

But I've got an error

`Warning:  preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier '('`

Can You guys help me please?
EDIT: $contents = curl_exec ($ch)

SOLVED: The error was cased becasue of wrong HTML on CURLed website:

```
  <span class="Menu1">Content</tr>
```

instead of:

```
 <span class="Menu1">Content</tr>
```

I didn't expected that someone can write wrong HTML. Thank You guys for help!

Comment: It will certainly be better to parse the HTML into DOM and then extract the content form the elements you want.

Comment: See [PHP: DOMDocument - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 6):

You forgot the first delimiter (`@`):

```
$contents = '<span class="Menu1">Artur $2000</span> somehtml <span class="Menu1">Mark $1000</span>';
preg_match_all('@<span class="Menu1">(.*?)</span>@si', $contents, $wynik2);

print_r($wynik2);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <span class="Menu1">Artur $2000</span>
            [1] => <span class="Menu1">Mark $1000</span>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Artur $2000
            [1] => Mark $1000
        )

)
*/
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I see an eempty array:
array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: $content Looks like this:
 
somehtml
<span class="Menu1">Artur $2000</span>
somehtml
<span class="Menu1">Mark $1000</span>

Comment: In other words: when I do echo $contents I see all HTML that I got from CURL.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this sign "`|`" in the start and the end of your regular expression :

```
preg_match_all("|<span class=\"Menu1\">(.*?)</span>|U",$contents,$wynik2);
```

Comment: I still see:
    array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } } 

contents contains a html document from CURL:
 $contents = curl_exec ($ch);

Comment: you should use this to get data from content of any site in php $contents = file_get_contents("path/to/your/domain");

Comment: Unfortunely I need to send POST[id] to see content of that site, that why i use CURL here

Comment: Your $contents is empty data you can try to echo it out!

Comment: you need to put this in your code curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); to get return data from your post page using CURL

Comment: Here is my code:

<?php
 
 
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://MYURL');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);// post
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'id_oferty=3800&send=Szczeg%F3%B3y'); //I need to send this to see content otherwise i see error
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  
  $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
  //print $contents;
  curl_close ($ch);  
  //print date('Y-m-d');  
      
     preg_match_all('|<span class=\"Menu1\">(.*?)</span>|U',$contents,$wynik2);

      
        var_dump($wynik2);
?>

Comment: Thank you Kannika! I solved that problem! (I'm not sure how to 'thank on stackoverflow)